# How to restore ".sh" association in bash?

Tags: shell-script, shebang

For some unknown reason I have a Debian 7 VM where .sh files that don't have a shebang line (#!/bin/sh) are no longer associated/executed by bash, ie. under bash, with "test.sh" an executable shell script (chmod'ed +x)

```
./test.sh
```

will do nothing, however

```
sh test.sh
```

will execute the script with bash.

When the shebang line is present, the script is executed.

Now, the exact same script file, with the same access rights, on other (theoretically similar) Debian 7 VMs, will be executed with "./test.sh" even when the shebang is not present.

Any idea about what could cause the difference?

**edit:** after the last batch of upgrade (apt-get upgrade on 2014-08-25) and reboot the problem is gone, previously I had tried rebooting, and it did not fix the issue. So I guess something got fixed in Debian, though I have no idea what looking at the updated packages.
If someone can shed some light on what was fixed, I will attribute the bounty.

Comment: Questions: (1) Which shell are you running, (2) What is the first character of this script, (3) Does the script have the execute permission?

Comment: (1) bash (Debian 7 default, unchanged), (2) a, (3) yes, "-rwxr-xr-x", even tried chmod 777. That set the problem seems to be gone with the last batch of "apt-get upgrade" (though none apparently related to bash).

Comment: Does the file contain any 8-bit characters? There is [a bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=496740) about bash incorrectly deciding that a file cannot be a script by its contents.

Comment: Only ASCII range, lower-case, space, a "-" and a "#" character are about as exotic as it got. The simpler sh was just two lines with apt-get update and apt-get upgrade respectively

Answer (score 0):

[`binfmt_misc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) is not loaded on that VM where it is on the others.

On debian, install it via the [`binfmt-support`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/binfmt-support) package.

Comment: Just checked, it's installed on none of the VMs.